# How to wait for async APIs in Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, webview

In `android`, there are many `async APIs` such as WebView's `evaluateJavascript`, which will `Asynchronously` evaluates `JavaScript` in the context of the currently displayed page. Usually an execution will just proceed to the successive statements after the call of an async API without any waiting.

But how can I *wait* until this call finishes its executing, before proceeding to the `successive statements`. For example,

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("JS code", new ValueCallback<String> {
    public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        //get JS return here
    }
});
//Remaining code
```

How can I make sure the remaining code is executed after `webview.evaluateJavascript` has finished its executing (i.e., its callback `onReceiveValue` has finished its executing).

Edit: To be more precise, what I want is that remaining code should be executed after onReceiveValue has finished executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find out a workaround by using JavaScript interface. The idea is that we create a bridge class that contains a method that takes the javascript execution result as input. Then we can obtain the result at the Java end. This method works because bridge methods are invoked by JavaScript code, which is run on another thread. We only need to wait on the UI thread for a little milliseconds, then the result is here for you. The following code is an illustration:

```
class Bridge {

    public String result = null;

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void putJsResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getJsResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
}

Bridge bridge = new Bridge();
wv.addJavascriptInterface(bridge, "bridge");
webview.evaluateJavascript("bridge.putJsResult(func())", null);
Thread.sleep(100);
//Result is there
String result = bridge.getJsResult();
```

Comment: i have to say it man realy you are genious <3 i liked this idea so much

Answer (score 1):

When you have to wait for code execution, a simple class to use is CountDownLatch.
An example for your problem can be:

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity {
    private volatile CountDownLatch jsLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private volatile String jsReceivedValue = null

    initWebView() {
        // webview init
        ...

        webview.evaluateJavascript("JS code", new ValueCallback<String> {
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                //get JS return here
                jsReceivedValue = value
                jsLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            // wait 60 seconds or assume there was some problem during the loading
            jsLatch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // thread interrupted or time elapsed
        }

        if (jsReceivedValue == null) {
            // show "problem during loading"
        } else {
            //Remaining code
        }   
    }
}
```

Note that waiting for code execution on main thread, can lead to unresponsive app.
You can show a loading spinner while using a simple thread to avoid this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        initWebView();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But CountDownLatch works when there are multiple threads. In my case, onReceiveValue is stilled called on the UI thread. When I follow your answer to make an app, I find the code after evaluateJavascript is still executed before the code in onReceiveValue.